# Simple URLSession example always fails with error

Tags: swift, macos, urlsession

My MacOS App is using a simple function which should establish a connection to a Server but I can't get it working, no matter what I try.

I copied an example from an other website but it does not work. I also watched other examples but most of them are very old and outdated.
Here is my code:

```
func connect(){
        
        // Set up the URL request
        let todoEndpoint: String = "https://www.google.com"
        guard let url = URL(string: todoEndpoint) else {
            print("Error: cannot create URL")
            return
        }
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        // set up the session
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
        
        // make the request
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            // do stuff with response, data & error here
            print(error as Any)
            print(response as Any)
        })
        task.resume()
        
    }
```

I get the following error

```
dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:11 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted
2018-02-16 15:02:19.437098+0100 [4869:445869] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: ServiceNotRunning(-65563)
2018-02-16 15:02:19.437839+0100 [4869:445869] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x604000166d80]: 10:-72000 Err(-65563)
2018-02-16 15:02:19.451077+0100 [4869:445860] Task <29B127C0-8865-4AF4-8960-C1F892824A3C>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1003 [10:-72000])
2018-02-16 15:02:19.451289+0100 [4869:445860] Task <29B127C0-8865-4AF4-8960-C1F892824A3C>.<1> finished with error - code: -1003
Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "Es wurde kein Server mit dem angegebenen Hostnamen gefunden." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60400024be80 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-72000, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=10}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.google.com/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.google.com/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=10, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-72000, NSLocalizedDescription=Es wurde kein Server mit dem angegebenen Hostnamen gefunden.})
```

What I am doing wrong. The localized description says: The host can not be found but its obviously that's not true. Any help I highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like something is blocking your request.

Comment: I created a new Project for iOS and there its working.

Comment: They key word is _for iOS_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is related to the `Outgoing connections`, be sure to have enabled such flag inside the `App Sandbox` panel:

[image]

Comment: OMG, thats the right solution. And I spent 2 hours to find out what it is. Thank you very much